# Bad config encountered during initialization jupyter_notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
[C 22:54:38.426 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 22:54:38.426 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: ''/home/u1025/git@gitlab.com:Hursheytung/ml.git''
```

I don't know why that operate this way
I changed a little bit in config.py because this is for class setting

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: it looks like you are adding a git repository as dir, can you share the output of `ls -al /home/u1025/git@gitlab.com:Hursheytung/ml.git`

Comment: ls: '/home/u1025/https://gitlab.com/Hursheytung/ml.git'에 접근할 수 없습니다: 그런 파일이나 디렉터리가 없습니다
it means there's no file or directory, but I already copy gitlab repository